# Unable to utilize ErrorMessage property with ValidateSet in Function

Tags: powershell, function, error-handling

I am currently practicing the use of functions in PowerShell and am running into an error. I created the function below to accept DC Super Hero names and return the name of the hero being passed to the function.

```
function Get-DCHero {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateSet('Batman','Superman','Aquaman','Wonder Woman','Flash',ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is not a DC Super Hero. Please trying one of the following: '{1}'")]
        [string]$Name
    )

    Write-OutPut "$Name is a DC Super hero."
}
```

As of now the function works properly without the `ErrorMessage` portion on the `ValidateSet`. When including the `ErrorMessage` portion I am receiving the following error:

```
Get-DCHero -Name

Property 'ErrorMessage' cannot be found for type 'System.Management.Automation.CmdletBindingAttribute'.  
At C:\Users\AAP8801\DCSuperHero.ps1:5 char:98
+ ... n','Flash', ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is not a DC Super Hero. Please tryi ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ErrorMessage = ...llowing: '{1}'":NamedAttributeArgume  
   ntAst) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundForType
```

When a parameter is passed to the function that is not part of the validation set I would like to able to edit the error message being throw. Can anyone tell me why I am unable to do this successfully?

Comment: The `ErrorMessage` property of `ValidateSet` was not exposed until PowerShell 6.2 - are you perhaps trying to run this code in Windows PowerShell (eg. version 5 and below)?

Comment: You can use `ValidateScript` in this case as an easy workaround

Answer (score 1):

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) explained in comments, the [`ErrorMessage` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.validatesetattribute.errormessage?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-validatesetattribute-errormessage) is available on the [`PowerShell SDK v6.2.0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.validatesetattribute.errormessage?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#applies-to) and above.

As a workaround in Windows PowerShell, you could use the [`ValidateScript` Attribute Declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validatescript-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2) or you could create your own attribute declaration by inheriting from [`ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.validateenumeratedargumentsattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), Base Type of the [`ValidateSet` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.validatesetattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0).

The following example can help you get started, and if you're interested in learning more, I would recommend you these nice articles from Kevin Marquette:

- [Powershell: Creating and using custom attributes](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-02-19-Powershell-custom-attribute-validator-transform/)
- [Powershell: Creating parameter validators and transforms](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-02-20-Powershell-creating-parameter-validators-and-transforms/)

##### Class Definition

```bash
using namespace System.Management.Automation

class MyDCHeroSet : ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute {
    [scriptblock] $Set
    [string] $ErrorMessage

    [void] ValidateElement([object] $Object) {
        $ValidValues = & $this.Set
        if($Object -notin $ValidValues) {
            throw [ValidationMetadataException]::new(
                [string]::Format(
                    $this.ErrorMessage,
                    $Object, ($ValidValues -join ',')
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

##### Implementation and Testing

```bash
function Get-DCHero {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [MyDCHeroSet(
            Set = { 'Batman', 'Superman', 'Aquaman', 'Wonder Woman', 'Flash' },
            ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is not a DC Super Hero. Please trying one of the following: '{1}'"
        )]
        [string] $Name
    )

    Write-Output "$Name is a DC Super hero."
}

Get-DCHero -Name Spiderman
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72104550/45375) by spelling out the **[`[ValidateScript()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) workaround** he mentions, which is slightly easier than defining a custom attribute class:

```sh
function Get-DCHero {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory)]
      [ValidateScript({
        $set = 'Batman','Superman','Aquaman','Wonder Woman','Flash'
        if ($_ -in $set) { return $true } # OK
        throw "'$_' is not a DC superhero. Please try one of the following: '$($set -join ',')'"
      })]
      [string]$Name
  )

  "$Name is a DC superhero."
}
```